# Local persistent Volume 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm getting started with persistent volumes and k8s. Im trying to use a local folder on my RH7 box w minikube installed. Im getting the error:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.
```

StorageClass.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

PersistentVolume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /usr/local/docker/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node
```

PersistentVolumeClaim.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
    name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      name: nginx-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-deployment
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: storage
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: example-local-claim
```

[root@localhost docker]# kubectl get pv

```
NAME               CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
example-local-pv   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Available           local-storage            76s
```

[root@localhost docker]# kubectl get pvc

```
NAME                  STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
example-local-claim   Pending                                      local-storage   75s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your persistent volume, your persistent volume has following node selector:

```
nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node
```

where your PV is trying to bind on node whose name is `my-node`, which it couldn't find as there is no node with that name. Please check your node-name using:

`kubectl get nodes`

And put the node name at the place of `my-node` and it will work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Too bad the persistent volume has "available" status while its configuration is not correct

Answer (score 0):

If you work with docker-desktop on windows, so try this:

1. Create dir in wsl:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v /:/k8s alpine mkdir /k8s/mnt/k8s
```

2. Create storageclass,vol,vol claim,pod:

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-storage
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50000Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/k8s
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - docker-desktop
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgredb
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres
  name: postgres
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14-alpine
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgredb
```