# kubespray: x node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/x nodes are available: x Preemption is not helpful for scheduling

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, storage-class-specifier

Although this questions has been asked many times, the provided [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112404/local-persistent-volume-1-nodes-didnt-find-available-persistent-volumes-to-bi) doesn't work for me.

Context:

I have

- x bare metal nodes on ubuntu
- installed kubespray on top of the x nodes
- an NFS share which is mounted to /data/xyz on all the nodes
- created a StorageClass, PersistentVolume, PersistentVolumeClaim and Deployment

Pod and PVC are in status 'Pending', PV in status 'Available'

kubectl describe po  gives

> x node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind. preemption: 0/x nodes are available: x Preemption is not helpful for scheduling

Please note that the node names in the PersistentVolume seem to be correct:

```
k get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
node1   Ready    control-plane,worker   19d   v1.26.3
node2   Ready    worker                 19d   v1.26.3
node3   Ready    worker                 19d   v1.26.3
node4   Ready    worker                 19d   v1.26.3
```

Here the corresponding yaml files

sc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

pv.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: localpv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data/xyz
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
            node2
            node3
            node4
```

pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvclocal
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
    name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      name: nginx-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-deployment
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data/xyz"
          name: storage
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvclocal
```

Answer (score 0):

You have create a PV with

> accessModes:
>
> - ReadWriteOnce

but requesting a volumen with

> accessModes:
>
> - ReadWriteMany.

PVC access mode must be included in PV access modes.

Try also using local-path provisioning included in addons.yaml config for provisioning volumes.

> kubespray/inventory/sample/group_vars/k8s_cluster/addons.yml